# cases and spacing between array rows

Tags: spacing, arrays

The space between two rows seems to differ if the cases environment is used. Have a look at the following example:

[image]

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{l}
f(x) =%
\begin{dcases}
-1 & x < 0 \\
1 & x > 0
\end{dcases} \\[2em]
g(x) = x \\[2em]
k(x) =%
\begin{dcases}
-1 & x < 0 \\
1 & x > 0
\end{dcases}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

I adjust the space between the rows by adding `2em` but it looks different. Does someone has an explanation for it?

Comment: @Andrew yes you are right. I changed the title. Thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`array` increases the line spacing in a construct such as `\\[2em]` by adding `2em` to its standard strut depth.  However, your construction produces something that is deeper than the standard strut already, so the adjustment is not as much as you thought you requested.  As you are using `dcases` which is in `mathtools` you could, or even should, use an `align*` environment instead, and that will space correctly.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\verb+array+ example with large depth on lines has a problem:
\[
\begin{array}{l}
  f(x) = \vrule height 2em depth 2em \\[2em]
  g(x) = x \\[2em]
  k(x) = \vrule height 2em depth 2em
\end{array}
\]

The \verb+align*+ version of the original code spaces correctly.

\begin{align*}
  f(x) &=%
  \begin{dcases}
    -1 & x < 0 \\
    1 & x > 0
  \end{dcases} \\[2em]
  g(x) &= x \\[2em]
  k(x) &=%
  \begin{dcases}
    -1 & x < 0 \\
    1 & x > 0
  \end{dcases}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I tried using `align*` without any luck because I need to left assign the left hand side of each equality. For example, rename the function `f(x)` to `foobar(x)`. Then `g(x)` and `k(x)` should be left assigned. But they aren't -- they are right assigned. This "coding convention" is used throughout our chair. So I have to stick to it. Otherwise I would love to use `align*`. Do you know if that is possible with the `align*` environment?

Comment: After searching a bit I found the following SX-Entry which solves my problem by using alignat: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10446/left-justify-with-align-on-in-align-environment

Comment: To left align as in your `array` example, just write the `&` at the beginning of each line instead of before the `=`, `&f(x) = ...` etc.