# Cases vs. Array environments

Tags: spacing, amsmath, arrays, cases

I would like to completely understand all the differences between using the `amsmath` environment `cases` and using the `array` environment to write functions with cases.

Here is my current understanding after reading other questions in the forum:

- `array` comes with padding on the left and the right. It can be suppressed using `{@{}ll@{}}` as explained in [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/349250/function-with-cases-or-array).
- `array` creates vertical spacing issues that I don't fully understand. See [this related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/126824/cases-and-spacing-between-array-rows).
- Both `array` and `cases` allow changing the space between lines using, for instance, `\\[2ex]`.
- It is much easier to change the alignment of columns with `array` than with `cases`.
- The left brace from `cases` seems to be taller than the left brace from `array`. But I don't understand why.
- Using `cases` is semantically more appropriate.
- `cases` requires loading `amsmath`

Overall, it seems like the default version of `cases` is better, but `array` is more customizable.

Are there other differences that I am missing? 
Is there an aspect of functions with cases that can be formatted using one of the environments but not the other one?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    |x| =
        \begin{cases}
            x & \text{if}\ x\geq 0\\
            -x & \text{if}\ x<0\\
        \end{cases}.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: function generated with cases]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
    |x| = 
        \left\{\begin{array}{ll}
            x & \text{if}\ x\geq 0\\
            -x & \text{if}\ x<0\\
        \end{array}\right..
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: function generated with array]

What I really want to know is which of the two environments is better and why. I have been using `array` for years, but I am considering switching to `cases`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code for `cases` in `amsmath` is just

```
\renewenvironment{cases}{%
  \matrix@check\cases\env@cases
}{%
  \endarray\right.%
}
\def\env@cases{%
  \let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
  \left\lbrace
  \def\arraystretch{1.2}%
  \array{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}%
}
```

so it is `array` with a column specification of `{@{}l@{\quad}l@{}}` and arraystretch of 1.2

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful!

Comment: You might mention `cases*` from `mathtools`, which allows `r`/`l` adjustments.  And, although not used in a "cases" situation, `array` also allows `c` to center a column.  (May as well be complete.)

Comment: You can use \hfil to center a column in cases if desired:
```\begin{cases}
\hfil x & \text{if } x\geq 0\\
-x & \text{if } x<0.
\end{cases}.```
    
More manipulation is possible with arrays, but when copyediting authors' tex files, I almost always change cases to the cases environment. The more "opportunity" authors are given to adjust spacing, the more likely it is that infelicities will be introduced. (In a similar vein, \text{if } is preferable to \text{if}\ or \text{if}\; etc.)
In my opinion, cases should be the default choice, unless you need to do something complicated.